# Div with content taking no space

Tags: css, html

In the following fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/ranisalt/jv5Lw/1/

The second `<header>` is for some reason taking the space of all but one of the previous divs. I don't really know how to explain the issue. "Account information" and "Character info" are the ONLY information inside the header, but for some reason it's background is taking space much before and after.

What is happening? CSS is a bit unpredictable...

Comment: Any `float` content does not get taken into account when block elements are computing their layout. Hence, the `<div>`s compute 0 height due to not having any non-floated content. `float` has some weird rules that take some getting used to.

Answer (score 0):

It's because of the floats.  You simply need to clear the floats on that last div:

```
.characters-info{
    clear: both;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jv5Lw/2/

Answer (score 0):

Add an overflow to the div account-info

> .account-info{
>       overflow: hidden;
>   }